# Is there any tool for creating a very simple 3d app without 3d programming?

Tags: 3d, modeling

I am looking for a way to create a simple 3d app that can rotate view and do simple tasks (like opening a door or pulling a drawer by clicking on them) and I wonder if there is a tool for this? I can create models with Auto CAD or Solid Works but I'm not still familiar with 3d programming and it will take so much time.
All I want from the application is to rotate view and to move/rotate objects.
Thanx!

Comment: Maybe a happy medium is to use a 3D game library such as Ogre or Unity3D, and import your models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Blender](http://blender.org/) is free and has a built in game engine. You can easily move and rotate objects without writing a line of code by using what they call logic bricks that are fairly intuitive and simple to set up.

If by "app" you mean an Iphone or Android application, there are people working on a branch of Blender that runs on Android, but I'm not sure how far along it is in development at the moment.

Comment: I wanna run it on Windows. Can I import the objects/textures from Auto CAD?

Comment: @Ehsan There is an addon for importing .dxf files, but I'm not sure how well it works since I've never used it and the documentation says it isn't finished.

Comment: Thanks; sounds good; I'll try it. (I'll vote as soon as my rep reaches 15!)